# Translating from Forms UserControl to WPF UserControl

Tags: wpf, winforms, wpf-controls

I am in the process of translating a Forms user control into a WPF user control. In my forms version do i overwrite a method called CreateHandle, where i hook up some events. I am having problems translating this to WPF as it do not have a CreateHandle method to overwrite, and i have been unable to figure out what else to overwrite. I am not able to do it in the constructor as the events i want to hook up is have not been created at this point.

Update: What i would like to do it have a method that is executed in WPF roughly at the some time the CreateHandle method in a forms user control would have.

Comment: You cannot *translate* or *convert* any WinForms controls to WPF - there is hardly any relation whatsoever and certainly no WPF version of `CreateHandle`. I suggest that you read a book explaining WPF before you try to re-create any WinForms UIs in WPF otherwise you'll have HUGE problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do it.

```
Public Sub New()
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        AddHandler Me.IsVisibleChanged, AddressOf OnView

    End Sub

    Private Sub OnView(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
        ' Do stuff here

        RemoveHandler Me.IsVisibleChanged, AddressOf OnView
    End Sub
```

Comment: Your "way to do it" has **absolutely** nothing to do with your question. If you are asking for a problem that *only you know* and don't state it in the question (but instead ask a completely different thing), how is the Stack Overflow community supposed to help you?

Comment: That said, check this link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2006/09/19/loadedvsinitialized.aspx